# Is this true for a convex function?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ satistfy:

1. $f'(x)<0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$,
2. $f''(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$,
3. $f(0)=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$.

Prove or disprove that $$x(f'(x))^2 > f(x)f'(x)+xf(x)f''(x).$$

Note that above inequality is satisfied with $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^\alpha}$ for $\alpha \geq 1$. I think the above inequality is true but I do not know to prove it.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: $f''(x)$ is only  on the right hand side, so can't you make $f''(x)$ really large for a  very small interval for $x$, and then the RHS would be bigger than the LHS?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Do you think that if $f''(x)$ is bounded then it works?

Comment: Please don't change the question after you asked it: make a new question instead.

Comment: @N.Quy . The functions $f(x)=(1+x)^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha\ge 0$ don't satisfy the inequality because $xf'(x)/f(x)$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent to
$$
 \left( x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)'  = 
x\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} - x\left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)^2 + \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}  < 0 \, .
$$
So you are asking if $x \mapsto x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is necessarily decreasing. But that need not be the case. A counterexample is $f(x) = \frac 1e e^{e^{-x}}$ where
$$
 x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = -x e^{-x}
$$
is strictly increasing on $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. In fact, my purpose is that the function $x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is increasing function. So  I want to ask another question, do you think which additional condition on $f$ makes the inequality true?

Comment: @MartinR : not relevant in the end, but there seems a sign error $f'(x)=-e^{-x}f(x)$.

Comment: @KurtG.: You are right, thanks! I'll fix it immediately. – This could mean that this example also serves as a counterexample to the follow-up question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4392407/42969.

Comment: It is an interesting example. Please see the edit to my answer in that follow up question.

Answer (score 1):

$f''(x)$ is only  on the right hand side, so you can make $f''(x)$ really large for a  very small interval for $x$, and then the RHS would be bigger than the LHS.

So for example, $f$ can be a quadratic with $f(0)=1; f(1)=1/2,$ and $f'(1) = -99/200.$

Then make $f''(x)$ very very large on some very very small interval $(1,1+\varepsilon)$ so that $f'(x)$ is small when $x\to (1+\varepsilon)^-.$ Then for some $c$ just less than $ (1+\varepsilon),\ xf(x)f''(x)$ is very very large positive,  $x(f'(x))^2$ is very very small positive, and $f(x)f'(x)$ is very small negative.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @N.Quy: This is not a comment, it is an *answer* to your question. You can choose to accept and/or vote on the answers, if you find them useful. But changing the question after receiving answers is bad style.