# Finding a sufficient condition for a property of convex function.

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ satistfy:

1. $f'(x)<0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$,
2. $f''(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$,
3. $f(0)=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$.

My questions are

1. Is the following statement true? There exists $N>0$ such that the functions $\dfrac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$ is increasing or equivalently
   $$x(f'(x))^2 > f(x)f'(x)+xf(x)f''(x), \forall  x\geq N.$$
2. If it is not true in general, I would like to find a sufficient condition to ensure it.

Thank you very much for any comments or discussion. Just one more thing, from [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392265/is-this-true-for-a-convex-function?noredirect=1#comment9184676_4392265), I know that, in general, the functions $\dfrac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$ is not increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the inequality $x(f'(x))^2 > f(x)f'(x)+xf(x)f''(x)$ is equivalent to $\dfrac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$ being *decreasing,* not increasing. Which means that https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4392291/42969 (after fixing the error pointed out by Kurt) also serves as a counterexample for (1).

Answer (score 2):

***A Partial Answer***

By your assumptions 1-3 the function is strictly decreasing and $f(0)=1$ and
$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0\,.$ This implies
$$
f(x)>0\quad\quad\forall x\ge 0\,.
$$
Indeed, if $f(x_0)<0$ then 3. implies that $f$ must have an absolute minimum from which it must increase. This is ruled out by 1. Further, if $f(x_0)=0$ we must now have $f(x)=0$ for all $x\ge x_0\,.$ This implies $f'(x)=0$ for all $x>x_0$ which is also ruled out by 1.

The function
$$
\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}=x\,(\log f(x))'
$$
clearly satisfies the following properties:
$$\tag{a}
g(x)<0\quad\text{ for all }x>0\,;\quad\text{ and }g(0)=0\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\tag{b}
\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0
$$
will ensure that on each interval $[N,+\infty)$ the function $g(x)$ must
be increasing for some $x\in [N,+\infty)\,.$

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ then, by de L'Hospital, a sufficient condition to ensure (b) would be
$$\tag{c}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)<0\,,\text{ and }\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(f'(x)+xf''(x)\Big)=0\,.
$$
An example of a function $f(x)$ for which $g(x)$ is increasing only on $[1,+\infty)$ is
$$
f(x)=\exp(e^{-x}-1)
$$
(found by MartinR in your previous post). This satisfies (a) and (b) but not (c).